# How to return the value of the same filed if the output is null - MS-ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a small question but it is very frustrating for me.

I am using MS-ACCESS to create some queries on a single table database.

One of the query I designed to fill the NULL values with the value of the same field but it doesn't work. Below is the query:

```
SELECT IIf(IsNull([Service Years]),[Service Years],[Service Years])
FROM Share
```

I basically want each record in the column to be filled with [Service Years].

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: If the field value is NULL then your IIF statement will try and put a NULL in there - looks like it's saying IF Service Years is NULL then enter the value of Service Years (which is NULL), other wise enter the value of Service Years (which is NULL) - or, as was written while I rambled on about NULL - as @Madhivanan said.

Comment: I got your point @DarrenBartrup-Cook, the problem is with my logic not the code. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - if the value of Service Years is NULL, then what is the value of the same field if it isn't NULL?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, The output consist of 6 rows, four of them shows Number 4 and the remaining two are NULL. I want these two to also show 4 also.

Comment: Ok, will it always be the same number in the other rows or do you want the maximum/minimum/average value available?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook,  the exact same number will do the trick.

Comment: If the other numbers are the same then you can take the Max, Min or Average - it will return the correct number so:  `SELECT IIf(IsNull([Service Years]), (SELECT MAX([Service Years]) FROM Share),[Service Years]) FROM Share`.  Not sure of the logic behind the request - but that should give the answer you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this

```
SELECT IIf(IsNull([Service Years]),'Service Years',[Service Years])
FROM Share
```

EDIT : One possible way is

```
SELECT IIf(
            IsNull([Service Years]),
            (SELECT MAX([Service Years]) from Share)),
            [Service Years]
           )
FROM Share
```

Comment: This will put Service Years as a text while I need its value.

Comment: If the value is NULL what value do you want?

Comment: The output consist of 6 rows, four of them shows Number 4 and the remaining two are NULL. I want these two to also show 4 also

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Nz*:

```
SELECT Nz([Service Years], 4) As ServiceYears
FROM Share
```